# Is this intended MySQL BETWEEN functionality?

Tags: mysql

As an example, at work we have an offers table with a start and end date. If the offer is always running it may be that the start of end date has a NULL value. I came a across a query which was having to do something like this

```
WHERE ( ISNULL(end_date) OR end_date > '2014-01-01 00:00:00' ) ...
```

I wanted to see if using BETWEEN would work, even if the start of end date was NULL.

```
select '2014-04-24 14:54:42' BETWEEN '2014-04-24 14:54:41' AND '2014-04-24 14:54:43'; -- 1
select '2014-04-24 14:54:42' BETWEEN '2014-04-24 14:54:43' AND '2014-04-24 14:54:41'; -- 0
select '2014-04-24 14:54:42' BETWEEN '2014-04-24 14:54:43' AND '2014-04-24 14:54:43'; -- 0

select '2014-04-24 14:54:42' BETWEEN '2014-04-24 14:54:43' AND NULL; -- 0
select '2014-04-24 14:54:42' BETWEEN NULL AND '2014-04-24 14:54:41'; -- 0
select '2014-04-24 14:54:42' BETWEEN NULL AND '2014-04-24 14:54:43'; -- NULL
select '2014-04-24 14:54:42' BETWEEN '2014-04-24 14:54:41' AND NULL; -- NULL
```

It seems to make sense when you get the NULL result for the last two queries as MySQL can't say for certain that the date is between the 2 values but from the data it does it it's not false. As we are using NULL for effectively low and high values, we could take NULL as true for this business logic.

Is this actually what MySQL is saying here? Or is this more of a quirk and should not be relied on?

Server version: 5.6.16-64.2-56-log Percona Server (GPL), Release 64.2, Revision 569

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is intended. Your answer, actually, lies inside [`AND`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/logical-operators.html#operator_and) operator mechanism in MySQL. It works in short evaluation scheme, and, even if one of your operands is `NULL`, the entire expression is evaluated to `false` (zero) if another operand is zero (false):

> Logical AND. Evaluates to 1 if all operands are nonzero and not NULL,
>   to 0 if one or more operands are 0, otherwise NULL is returned.
>
> mysql> SELECT 1 && 1;
>
> ```
>     -> 1
> ```
>
> mysql> SELECT 1 && 0;
>
> ```
>     -> 0
> ```
>
> mysql> SELECT 1 && NULL;
>
> ```
>     -> NULL
> ```
>
> mysql> SELECT 0 && NULL;
>
> ```
>     -> 0
> ```
>
> mysql> SELECT NULL && 0;
>
> ```
>     -> 0
> ```

Since [`BETWEEN`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between) is fully equivalent to evaluation of two expressions with `AND` : `(min <= expr AND expr <= max)` your expression with `NULL`-s is equal to:

```
SELECT @min<=@date_value AND @date_value<=@max
```

(I've replaced values to indicate structure). Therefore, if one of expressions is evaluated to false (zero) - result of whole expression will be false (zero), and **not** `NULL`. But if it's not - then result will be `NULL` because we can't say anything about `1 AND NULL` (like in your two last queries).

So, resolution: **yes**, it's intended. **Yes**, you can rely on fact, that `0 AND NULL` will result to `0` (same for `1 OR NULL`, resulting in `1`).